# Ways to construct sets of magic the gathering factions by colour combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

[Magic: the Gathering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) is a 25 year old card game where each card can have a 'colour identity'. There are five such identities ([White (W), Blue (U), Black (B), Red (R), Green (G)] ignoring colourless), and when a new collection of cards are released they are often grouped into factions.

Factions often have more than one colour identity (Cards in the 'Blue Red' (UR) faction may be Blue, Red or Blue and Red).

Further, a set is always* colour balanced (meaning that the same number of identities exist across all colours, e.g. you might have one set of factions UBR,WRG,UG,WB wherein all the colours appear twice in each faction).

What are all the ways of constructing the sets of distinct factions, for $n$ factions? Is there a pattern I can use based off of small numbers of factions?

*Exceptions exist outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Presumably all factions in a set have different, um, identity palettes?

Comment: @joffan I think I know what you mean? If so yes. They need to be distinct.

Comment: I am building an answer.  Current estimates are a little under 4 million total faction groupings, not counting those that include colorless or rainbow, though any given one has up to 39 others that it is similar to via symmetric relationships.  My code sucks though, mostly because of trying to take advantage of these symmetries, and I haven't been able to verify that it's fully correct yet.

Comment: @DanUznanski I'm not sure if symetric relationships (e.g. the order doe matter) should count? because WUBR,G and G,WUBR should be the same, right?

Comment: Well, it's more like -- if I have W,BG,UR, I can also have B,RW,UG.  Or UBRG,WUR,WBG. or a thing with 27 different factions, just not those three.  All told we get a symmetry group with 40 elements, assuming we respect the actual pairing types between colors: there are ten ways to pick color order, then we can replace every faction with its counterpart, then we can replace the list with everything that isn't in the list.

Comment: @DanUznanski does it help if you only describe a simple number of factions (4 or 5 is common in the game, perhaps for simplicity) and then help us extrapolate? Would it help if we restricted the factions to be more than one colour? I'm just thinking of ways to make your answer writable

Comment: I have a different plan at the moment, which may make it tractable to actually write out the full list of faction lists.  Just have to get home from work to try it...

Comment: Well okay I won't leave you hanging too much: many faction lists can be decomposed into shorter faction lists. It may be possible to come up with a tractable list of faction groups by short circuiting when we find that an existing faction list is contained within the list we're looking at

Answer (score 2):

There are 133 distinct *canonical primitive* faction groups.

A *primitive* faction group is one that does not contain any other faction groups; all non-primitive faction groups can be expressed as a combination of primitive faction groups.

There's still quite a lot of those - some 967 - so what we also need to do is pick a way to coalesce those that are similar into a single *canonical* faction group.  For this, I have chosen the following: each faction is represented by a number, found by summing the values `W = 1, U = 2, B = 4, R = 8, G = 16` for that faction.  Then, a faction group is represented by another number, $\sum_f 2^f$ for each faction number in the group.  THe canonical faction group for a particular group is the smallest faction group number among the (up to) ten similar faction groups, where things are similar if rotation and reflection of the faction group around the color wheel can make them match up.

Here is the full list of canonical faction groups.

`0x00000001 -
0x00010116 W,U,B,R,G # five pures
0x00010118 R,G,WU,B # allies vs pures
0x00010124 R,G,U,WB # enemies vs pures
0x00010180 R,G,WUB # shard vs pures
0x00010240 G,WR,UB # enemies vs allies vs pure
0x00010420 G,UR,WB # enemies vs enemies vs pure
0x00010810 G,WUR,B # wedge vs pures
0x00011008 G,WU,BR # allies vs allies vs pure
0x00018000 G,WUBR # quartet vs pures
0x00024000 WG,UBR # allies vs shard
0x00042000 UG,WBR # enemies vs wedge
0x80000000 WUBRG # rainbow
0x00031442 W,UB,UR,BR,G,WG
0x00031480 WUB,UR,BR,G,WG
0x00031840 UB,WUR,BR,G,WG
0x00032440 UB,UR,WBR,G,WG
0x00051224 U,WB,WR,BR,G,UG
0x00051280 WUB,WR,BR,G,UG
0x00051820 WB,WUR,BR,G,UG
0x00054220 WB,WR,UBR,G,UG
0x00061240 UB,WR,BR,WG,UG
0x00061420 WB,UR,BR,WG,UG
0x00068110 B,R,WUBR,WG,UG
0x00069000 WG,UG,BR,WUBR
0x00092140 UB,R,WBR,G,WUG
0x00092410 B,UR,WBR,G,WUG
0x00094120 WB,R,UBR,G,WUG
0x00094210 B,WR,UBR,G,WUG
0x00096000 G,WUG,WBR,UBR
0x00128104 U,R,WUBR,WG,BG
0x00128400 WG,UR,BG,WUBR
0x00140620 WB,WR,UR,UG,BG
0x00148102 W,R,WUBR,UG,BG
0x00148200 WR,UG,BG,WUBR
0x00182400 UR,WUG,BG,WBR
0x00184200 WR,WUG,BG,UBR
0x00188100 R,WUG,BG,WUBR
0x00210940 UB,R,WUR,G,WBG
0x00211804 U,WUR,BR,G,WBG
0x00214800 G,WUR,WBG,UBR
0x00240910 B,R,WUR,UG,WBG
0x00241800 UG,WUR,BR,WBG
0x00248100 R,UG,WBG,WUBR
0x00412800 G,WUR,WBR,UBG
0x00421800 WG,WUR,BR,UBG
0x00428100 R,WG,UBG,WUBR
0x01021048 WU,UB,BR,WG,RG
0x01028014 U,B,WUBR,WG,RG
0x01028040 RG,WG,UB,WUBR
0x01082040 RG,WUG,WBR,UB
0x01084012 W,B,UBR,WUG,RG
0x01084020 RG,WUG,WB,UBR
0x01088010 RG,WUG,B,WUBR
0x01208004 RG,U,WBG,WUBR
0x01808000 RG,WUBG,WUBR
0x02014080 G,WRG,UBR,WUB
0x02048010 WRG,UG,B,WUBR
0x02408000 WRG,UBG,WUBR
0x02804000 WRG,UBR,WUBG
0x04208000 URG,WBG,WUBR
0x08108000 WURG,BG,WUBR
0x00161680 WUB,WR,UR,BR,WG,UG,BG
0x01061860 WB,UB,WUR,BR,WG,UG,RG
0x01186006 W,U,WBR,UBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x01186008 WU,WBR,UBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x01188240 UB,WR,WUBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x01188420 WB,UR,WUBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x0118a004 U,WBR,WUBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x0118c002 W,UBR,WUBR,WUG,BG,RG
0x01244812 W,B,WUR,UBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x01244820 WB,WUR,UBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x01248240 UB,WR,WUBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x01248810 B,WUR,WUBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x01249008 WU,BR,WUBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x0124c002 W,UBR,WUBR,UG,WBG,RG
0x01284810 B,WUR,UBR,WUG,WBG,RG
0x01286004 U,WBR,UBR,WUG,WBG,RG
0x01288140 UB,R,WUBR,WUG,WBG,RG
0x0128c000 UBR,WUBR,WUG,WBG,RG
0x01422814 U,B,WUR,WBR,WG,UBG,RG
0x01422840 UB,WUR,WBR,WG,UBG,RG
0x01428420 WB,UR,WUBR,WG,UBG,RG
0x01428810 B,WUR,WUBR,WG,UBG,RG
0x01429008 WU,BR,WUBR,WG,UBG,RG
0x01482810 B,WUR,WBR,WUG,UBG,RG
0x01488120 WB,R,WUBR,WUG,UBG,RG
0x0148a000 WBR,WUBR,WUG,UBG,RG
0x01602804 U,WUR,WBR,WBG,UBG,RG
0x01608108 WU,R,WUBR,WBG,UBG,RG
0x01608800 WUR,WUBR,WBG,UBG,RG
0x02144182 W,WUB,R,UBR,UG,BG,WRG
0x02144280 WUB,WR,UBR,UG,BG,WRG
0x02148180 WUB,R,WUBR,UG,BG,WRG
0x02148420 WB,UR,WUBR,UG,BG,WRG
0x02149008 WU,BR,WUBR,UG,BG,WRG
0x02184180 WUB,R,UBR,WUG,BG,WRG
0x02186004 U,WBR,UBR,WUG,BG,WRG
0x02188410 B,UR,WUBR,WUG,BG,WRG
0x0218c000 UBR,WUBR,WUG,BG,WRG
0x02244810 B,WUR,UBR,UG,WBG,WRG
0x02249004 U,BR,WUBR,UG,WBG,WRG
0x0224c000 UBR,WUBR,UG,WBG,WRG
0x02482410 B,UR,WBR,WUG,UBG,WRG
0x02486000 WBR,UBR,WUG,UBG,WRG
0x02604800 WUR,UBR,WBG,UBG,WRG
0x02849000 BR,WUBR,UG,WUBG,WRG
0x02902404 U,UR,WBR,BG,WUBG,WRG
0x02908400 UR,WUBR,BG,WUBG,WRG
0x02c02400 UR,WBR,UBG,WUBG,WRG
0x04602800 WUR,WBR,WBG,UBG,URG 
0x04829000 BR,WUBR,WG,WUBG,URG
0x04908200 WR,WUBR,BG,WUBG,URG
0x06808010 B,WUBR,WUBG,WRG,URG
0x08249000 BR,WUBR,UG,WBG,WURG
0x08429000 BR,WUBR,WG,UBG,WURG
0x08608100 R,WUBR,WBG,UBG,WURG
0x12084080 WUB,UBR,WUG,WRG,BRG
0x12808004 U,WUBR,WUBG,WRG,BRG
0x18028040 UB,WUBR,WG,WURG,BRG
0x18048020 WB,WUBR,UG,WURG,BRG
0x18208004 U,WUBR,WBG,WURG,BRG
0x18808000 WURG,WUBG,BRG,WUBR
0x24808000 URG,WUBG,WBRG,WUBR
0x01686800 WUR,WBR,UBR,WUG,WBG,UBG,RG
0x06186080 WUB,WBR,UBR,WUG,BG,WRG,URG
0x06909008 WU,BR,WUBR,BG,WUBG,WRG,URG
0x09609008 WU,BR,WUBR,WBG,UBG,RG,WURG
0x12848420 WB,UR,WUBR,UG,WUBG,WRG,BRG
0x16808080 WUB,WUBR,WUBG,WRG,URG,BRG
0x18248240 UB,WR,WUBR,UG,WBG,WURG,BRG
0x18608800 WUR,WUBR,WBG,UBG,WURG,BRG
0x68808000 WUBR,WUBG,WURG,WBRG,UBRG # five quartets`

[Source Code](https://gist.github.com/DUznanski/d777f145f5ede28ebc0a266c5e19ee2e)

Comment: This is really interesting! Curious about the patterns, but I'll have to look at the source code to understand it.

Comment: The source code is pretty optimized, working with bit operations instead of proper sets (which I can do because I know the entire universe of elements), to make it so it can actually get anything done in a reasonable time, but it still takes ten minutes.  I'm thinking about drawing the diagrams for these but it's pretty annoying.