# How many Color Balanced sets can you make with n colors?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

You have `n` colors and you make nonempty sets from them. A set of these color sets is *color balanced* if each color is in the same number of the color sets.

Ex. For `n=3`, using Red Green Blue (RGB) as the colors, the set { {RG}, {RB}, {GB} } would be *color balanced* as each color is in two color sets. As would:

{ {R}, {G}, {B} }
{ {B}, {G}, {RB}, {RG} }
{ {RGB}, {R}, {BG}}
{ }
{ {RGB}, {RG}, {RB}, {GB}, {R}, {G}, {B}}

The sets { {R}, {G} } and { {RGB}, {R}, {G} } would not be color balanced for `n=3`, as Blue (B) fails to appear in as many color sets as Red (R) and Green (G).

---

How many color balanced sets can you create with `n` colors? The obvious brute force method is to a. enumerate all the color sets b. enumerate all sets of color sets and check each one for color balance. With this I found:

3 colors: 20 color balanced sets
4 colors: 880
5 colors: 5,280,908

([code](https://gist.github.com/alro5921/2d80ac31ed11980bd04e08065d5bbd6d)) But this requires $2^{2^n}$ color balance checks, which is obviously intractable for larger `n`.

**Question**: Is there a more tractable algorithm or combinatoric trick for finding the number of color balanced sets you can make with `n` colors? How many color balanced sets are there using 7 colors?

---

[We've broached this subject before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2848997/ways-to-construct-sets-of-magic-the-gathering-factions-by-colour-combinations), though not with this particular question. [Dan Uznanski](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/167895/dan-uznanski) came up with a list of primitive canonical groups for `n=5`, where all non-primitive color balanced sets are combinations of these primitive groups. That seems like a promising direction, but it's not clear to me how you'd actually form and count the non-canonical sets from these primitive bases, or if you can actually find the primitives without brute forcing (as I think [Dan did)](https://gist.github.com/DUznanski/d777f145f5ede28ebc0a266c5e19ee2e).

The motivation for this question was the same: Magic the Gathering expansions are almost always divided into "factions" that have colors associated with them (the color sets). One of the most popular expansions, for instance, is divided by all the 2-color pairs (Green-Blue, Green-Red, Green-White, Green-Black, Blue-Red etc). The factions have always been color balanced within the expansion, and I was curious exactly how many configurations there were.

Comment: [OEOS](https://oeis.org/search?q=20%2C+880%2C+5280908&language=english&go=Search) doesn't seem to have an entry for this.

Comment: There will be colour counter-balanced set pairs, such as the pair { {R}, {G} } and { {R,G} } and the pair { (R,G}, {R,B} } and { {R}, {R,G,B} } where the two paired sets have the same colour membership. A colour-balanced set will remain colour-balanced when one of the paired sets is removed and replaced by the other (if the removed set is a subset of the colour-balanced set and the added set does not overlap it). I don't know whether this note will be helpful or not, but my guess is that the pairs would be easier to enumerate.

Comment: If you don't count the empty family you have [OEIS A319190](https://oeis.org/A319190).

Comment: @BillyJoe Damn, good catch! I even tried a few variants when Arthur posted his, should've tried a few more I suppose.

Comment: It would be interesting to count also the number of non-isomorphic families, e.g. $11$ for $n=3$. In other words, those that are not equal up to a permutation of the colors.

Comment: @BillyJoe That I think you can construct from primitive faction groups, as [Dan Uznanski found](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2849917/555812). Since by definition all non-primitive CB sets are unions of primitive CB, you can quickly brute force the non-primitives by just by going down the list and seeing if you can union two primitives (i.e they're disjoint), and then see if that union is disjoint with other primitives down the list etc. Seems to work for `n=3` at least

Comment: (err disjoint for some rotation/reflection of color. But that's still reasonably quick to check)